# TinyMCE Spellchecker Rails not working

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, tinymce

I am currently using the tinymce-rails gem found here https://github.com/spohlenz/tinymce-rails and I am having trouble getting the spellchecker to initialize. The TinyMCE editor works fine otherwise.

Javascript:

```
tinyMCE.init({
  mode: "specific_textareas",
  editor_selector: "tinymce",
  theme: "advanced",
  theme_advanced_toolbar_location: "top",
  theme_advanced_toolbar_align: "left",
  theme_advanced_statusbar_location: "bottom",
  theme_advanced_buttons1: "bold,italic,underline,bullist,numlist",
  theme_advanced_buttons3: "tablecontrols,fullscreen,spellchecker",
  plugins: "table,autoresize,fullscreen,spellchecker",
  width: "100%",
  height: 400,
  autoresize_min_height: 400,
  autoresize_max_height: 800,
  language:"en",
  spellchecker_languages: "+English=en"
});
```

The erb `<%= f.text_area :completed, :class => "tinymce", :size => 500 %>` generates the following:

```
<body id="tinymce" class="mceContentBody " contenteditable="true" onload="window.parent.tinyMCE.get('report_completed').onLoad.dispatch();" spellcheck="false" style="overflow-y: hidden; padding-bottom: 50px;" dir="ltr">
```

I note that the spellcheck field is false, but I'm not sure why, or if that is actually related to what the problem is.

Answer (score 3):

[This post](http://webonrails.com/2008/08/08/configuring-tinymce-spellchecker-with-rails-application/), and [this post](http://hasham2.blogspot.com/2008/02/getting-tinymce-30-spellchecker-to-work.html) suggest that it's a bit more involved than just adding it to the list of plugins & setting the language.

Both posts suggest using `aspell` to check spellings, adding the line `:spellchecker_rpc_url => "/users/spellchecker",` to the TinyMCE configuration, and writing some custom Controller code.

I hope those links help you out.

Answer (score 3):

Possible duplicate: [TinyMCE 4.0.5 spell check not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18626276/tinymce-4-0-5-spell-check-not-working/21173658#21173658)

According to what I've found elsewhere, the spellchecker plugin was powered by Google service - which has been retired. So at this time there does not appear to be an integrated TinyMCE spellchecker solution.

However, you CAN enable the browser's built-in spellchecker by doing the following:

```
tinymce.init({
    browser_spellcheck : true,
});
```

Be sure to remove spellchecker from your toolbar and your plugins list.

Comment: OMG I love you! Your solution is just as good as the others and about 1000x less work

Comment: Glad to be of service, @Gerry!

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to easily get as-you-type-check working, just by adding this to my `config/tinymce.yml`

```
browser_spellcheck:
  - true
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using the suggestions in one of @James Chevalier's [links](https://hasham2.blogspot.com/2008/02/getting-tinymce-30-spellchecker-to-work.html) and following the [TinyMCE v4 docs](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs-4x/plugins/spellchecker/) to write this:

```rb
# config/routes.rb

post 'tinymce/spellcheck'
```

```rb
# app/controllers/tinymce_controller.rb

class TinymceController < ApplicationController
  skip_forgery_protection

  respond_to :json

  def spellcheck
    suggestions = check_spelling_new(
      spellcheck_params[:text],
      spellcheck_params[:lang]
    )

    render json: {words: suggestions}
  end

  private

  def spellcheck_params
    params.permit(:method, :lang, :text)
  end

  def check_spelling_new(text, lang)
    suggestions = {}

    spell_check_response = `echo "#{text}" | aspell -a -l #{lang}`

    if spell_check_response.present?
      spelling_errors = spell_check_response.split(' ').slice(1..-1)

      spelling_errors.length.times do |i|
        spelling_errors[i].strip!

        if spelling_errors[i].to_s.start_with?('&')
          match_data = spelling_errors[i + 1]
          suggestion_count = spelling_errors[i + 2].to_i

          suggestions[match_data] ||= []

          suggestion_count.times do |k|
            suggestions[match_data] << spelling_errors[i + k + 4].gsub(',', '')
          end
        end
      end
    end

    suggestions
  end
end
```

```js
// tinymce.js

tinymce.init({
  ...,
  spellchecker_rpc_url: '.../tinymce/spellcheck'
});
```

You must have [aspell](https://zoomadmin.com/HowToInstall/UbuntuPackage/aspell) and the required dictionaries installed, of course.

I don't recommend doing it for new projects, do what @wloescher and @Ruby Racer said. I've only done this for a legacy project that must support it.